# How do I get the full POST WebRequest-sourcecode as it appears in Fiddler/the WinInet Cache?

Tags: c#

The following code sample seems to be doing what it should, as fiddler gets exactly the Data that I want:

```
public void SOSampleGet(string url)
        {
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Host = "somesitename.abc";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true
            webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            System.Net.Cache.HttpRequestCachePolicy a = new 
            ...

            string postData = "key1=value1&key2=value2&...
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

My problem: string responceFromServer has important parts at the top, middle and bottom of the source missing, which are however visible when I look at the request I made with Fiddler, or check the cached source

Are they somehow injected afterwards? Or do i need to decode/decrypt the source twice? I have no Idea what I am missing

Comment: Could you give an example of something missing?

Comment: mostly javascripts which inject the important site info

Comment: Is it rest request  ?

Comment: Haven't heard of a rest request before, but after looking it up, this might be going in the right direction! How can I find out if it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
responceFromServer only has the outerHTML.

I needed to install the HtmlAgilityPack to solve this.
I only had to change the last paragraph as followed to access the needed html data:

```
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
var temp = response.GetResponseStream();
HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlDocument();
Doc.Load(temp);
string innerTxt = Doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```